# Web Api Controller Value passing value to the method

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I am new to asp.net web API so please bare if it's a silly question, I am not able to send value to the methods.
the code goes below, in WebApiConfig

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{value}",
            defaults: new { value = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Inside the controller i have a method

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    [ActionName("Test")]
    public string Test([FromBody]string value)
    {
        return value;
    }
```

Inside javascript I am doing $.ajax, with

```
url: "WebApi2/api/FormsDesinger/Test"
```

`data:"{'value':'Some Value'}"`

Whenever i do a the ajax call, the method is called, but the "value" is null.
Can anybody please let me know what is that i am doing wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually found the solution by trail and error method, but still looking for the answers, why it din't work in the first place. the working code here it goes.

Method:

```
[AcceptVerbs("POST", "GET")]
    [ActionName("Test1")]
    public string Test(string id)
    {
        return id;
    }
```

WebApiConfig:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
        );
```

In `$.ajax` i am passing id as part of url,
`url:"WebApi2/api/FormsDesinger/Test1?id=123", data:null`

This is the working fine, but i still want to achieve passing values as part of `data` in `$.ajax`.

Guys, Please feel free to comment and I am ready to try other alternatives as well.

Answer (score 1):

- HTTP `GET` request does not contains a `body`. and your `value`
  parameter is bound using the `[FromBody]` attribute.

  Change your `[AcceptVerbs]` attribute to accept `POST` and change
  your Ajax request to `POST` as well (if it's not right now).
- WebApi expects primitives in the body to be encoded as `=value` (without the 'key'). so you need to change your Ajax request accordingly:

  `data: "=" + value`

Comment: Even tried that, but with this change, I am getting the below Error "The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'."

Comment: What exactly did you try? you need to change everything to `POST`, not `GET`.

Comment: If you include the header Content-Type:application/json in the request, web api should be able to understand the json body, no?

Comment: @haim770 : `[AcceptVerbs("POST")]` and ajax request to `POST`

Comment: I don't think so, since [FromBody] expects the value to be encoded in a special way (as described in my answer) and not json.

Comment: You changed to 'POST' and the error says that 'GET' is not allowed?

Comment: @haim770 : Yes, After changing to `POST` error is `the requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.`

Comment: @haim770, After doing `data: "=" + value` change it's hitting the server but value is null

Comment: Please post the full request data here (try using the browser inspector / Firebug etc).

Comment: @haim770 Request Header: `POST /EnterpriseConsole/BPMUITemplates/Default/NextGenForms/WebApi2/api/FormsDesinger/Test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 5
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://localhost:8000
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
` Request PayLoad: `=abcd`

Comment: Change your `content-type' to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded `.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion in the other answer (which I actually expected to sort your problem) a few things to try:

1. Your route is `"api/{controller}/{action}/{value}"`
   The controller is `Test` but the action is also `Test` - try POSTing to this url instead:
   /EnterpriseConsole/BPMUITemplates/Default/NextGenForms/WebApi2/api/FormsDesinger‌​/Test/Test
   (note double `Test` at the end)
2. Add constraint to the Route template to only support POST and remove GET from AcceptVerbs
   `constraints: new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }` (after your defaults)
3. Remove the `{action}` bit from the route template and see if that changes things
4. Post here your updated controller code